# Is there any way in perl to run multiple linux commands and keep environmental variables between them

Tags: linux, perl

I have a perl script and I want to do the following:

system("source myscript.sh");

myscript.sh exports multiple envs but these are lost once system completes so that if I now do:

system("echo $SOME_VAR");

It fails because $SOME_VAR was exported by myscript.sh and lost when system completed.

This is a simple example but in my actually use case myscript.sh is a complex script and I want to execute 10 to 20 system commands afterwards that depend on env vars from it.

Thank you in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that myscript.sh doesn't print anything,

```
%new_env = ();
open SCRIPT_ENV, 'source myscript.sh; printenv|';
map {/(.*?)=(.*)/ and do {$new_env{$1} = $2}} <SCRIPT_ENV>;
close SCRIPT_ENV;
%ENV = %new_env;
```

If the script myscript.sh prints something you will have to do something more elaborate.

Comment: It doesn't have to be too elaborate: 'source myscript.sh > /dev/null; printenv|' ought to do it.

Comment: @DavidHammen Hi David, Thank you for your answer. Your solution works perfectly on Linux. My perl script unfortunately also has to run on solaris and on solaris I have the following issue: "sh: source: not found" is there a way I can force the script to use bash instead of sh?

Comment: Linux uses bash (Bourne-again shell) to execute .sh files, solaris uses Bourne shell. `source` is a C-shell command used to execute a C-shell script in the current environment that the bash implementers imported into bash. The Bourne shell equivalent of `source some_script.sh` is `. some_script.sh`. Dot works in both bash and sh, so change that `source myscript.sh` to `. myscript.sh` and everything should be good.

Comment: Thank you so much again for your response. Sorry I forgot to mention this in my previous reply but unfortunately myscript.sh is a bash script that will only run in bash it wont run in sh so for this reason I am looking to force solaris to run the bash shell rather than the sh shell.

Comment: Do you have bash on solaris? If you do, explicitly force the use of bash via `open SCRIPT_ENV, 'bash -c ". resetenv.sh; printenv"|';`

Comment: @Gary: Re "works perfectly": In that case you should accept this as the answer. It is the polite thing to do at this site. (So shoot me; I'm pimpin' for points. That does not detract from the fact this is the right thing to do here.)

Comment: Sorry this was the first question I've asked on this site and I didn't know I could accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to run a wrapper shell script that looks like this:

```
source myscript.sh
env
```

and then read the output of the 'env' command and set the environment within your perl program from that.

So you need to run the wrapper script like this:

```
open CMD, "wrapper.sh|";
```